# Bathroom vent installation

Tags: vent, stove

What kind of contractor do I call to have a bathroom vent installed? I also need a vent put in above my stove. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not many contractors I know would touch such a small project. I think you're looking for a **handyman**. E.g., I live in Chicago and there's a business called [HandiCo](http://www.yelp.com/biz/handico-inc-chicago). They'll do anything you want, after you pay them over a hundred dollars to show up, and about half of that per hour, until it's done.

You could try [handyman.com](http://handyman.com/), a contractor locator service.

I have no affiliation with either of these companies, nor have I used them.